# When post starts with image, subscription email goes bad

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification, rendering

I have a tag filter subscription sending me daily email for questions with this tag.

Today I opened this daily email and saw this strange thing:

[image: bad email screenshot]

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800602/javascript-for-checkbox-checked), which I fixed of course. [The original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/091610cd-a494-486d-a14b-3513ff837a48/view-source) of the question, causing this misbehavior is:

```
![java script for all ths checkbox in the ASPxgrid.. when i click on any of the header checkbox all the rows belpw that must be checked.. example: when i click on select all checkbox of header than all the checkbox shown in grid must be checked and viseversa.. also when i click on any select row checkbox than that particular row must be selected..
also i have chid and parent node as admin has role wise menu and role details then clicking on cell[1][1] that is admin row first cell, then it should check or uncheck its child node too.. please help me as soon as possible.. i have used ASP checkbox..][1]


  [sample]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/czyQI.png
```

In this case, looks like the whole post was one big image as far as the rendering goes however I believe it will happen with any post that starts with image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed now. Thanks for starting the investigation.

We were using markdown to generate our filter subscription emails. Since this question's body began with `![`, and since we truncate the bodies after 200 characters, the markdown parser matched up the question's `![` with the user link's `]`, thereby hyperlinking a swath of HTML which shouldn't have been hyperlinked.

We now generate these emails with raw HTML, so this shouldn't happen again.

Comment: Bottom line it's sheer luck - having such post with the specific tag (that was actually not relevant to the question) - thanks for the quick fix!