# HTML not escaped in question titles in emails

Tags: bug, email, character-escaping

HTML is not escaped in question titles in emails.

For example, this email:

> [image]

Links to this question:

[Can I make a <button> not submit a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314989/can-i-make-a-button-not-submit-a-form/3315021)

Comment: Nice bug! *planning an XSS attack*

Comment: It happened before... kind of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126492/when-post-starts-with-image-subscription-email-goes-bad (either regression of the fix, or the fix was never applied to titles)